# One line conditional boolean return statement

Tags: perl, return, conditional-statements

Lately I came to this Perl code segment:

```
if($foo eq "foo") {
    return 1;   
}
my $bar = GetBar();
return ($bar eq "bar")
```

If the value of `$foo` was ever equals to `foo`, it would return true immediately, without calling `GetBar`. Assuming that this would only occur whenever the statement `$foo eq "foo"` was true, isn't there a oneline conditional boolean return statement that looks like:

```
return only if $foo eq "foo";
```

Meaning: Return value of `$foo eq "foo"` only if `$foo eq "foo"` is true.

I'm curious if there is such statement in any coding language.

Comment: What is your actual question? Can `if (EXPR) { return EXPR; }` be written as `return EXPR if EXPR;` in Perl? If so, the answer is yes.

Comment: Unfortunately a comment has to be longer than 3 characters, so I added this sentence. No!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Perl, you can't return the value returned by the comparison if said value is true, but

```
if ($foo eq 'foo') { return 1; }
```

can be written as

```
return 1 if $foo eq 'foo';
```

Like flow control statements, statement modifiers are documented in [perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html).

---

By the way, the entirety of the code you posted can be simplified to the following:

```
return $foo eq 'foo' || GetBar() eq 'bar';
```

Comment: Lovely, that's close to what I wanted. And thanks for the simplification example, wouldn't have thought that way.

Comment: I'd avoid the simplification.  It can be good to have sub calls in a separate statement for easier debugging.  The original code in the question is perfect from that perspective.

Comment: @ysth, It's premature to add debugging hooks. There's absolutely no indication that any are needed.

Answer (score 2):

You say "Return value of $foo eq "foo" only if $foo eq "foo" is true."

You can do that simply by

```
return 1 if $foo eq 'foo';
```

if `eq` isn't overloaded and 1 is the only possible true value.

If it is overloaded and might return something other than false or 1, you can do:

```
$_ and return $_ for $foo eq 'foo';
```

but only if your goal is to try to produce bad code.

```
my $foofoo = $foo eq 'foo';
return $foofoo if $foofoo;
```

would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

Something like a ternary operator perhaps (in python).

```
return True if foo == 'foo' else bar == 'bar'
```

Comment: I have more experience with Perl, but now that I am also writing a lot of Python I miss Python's TrueValue-IfCondition-FalseValue syntax for IF-expressions.  ($cond?$trueValue:$falseValue) can de less readable.  Q: is there any Perl idiom that allows the Python order?

Comment: ^ do you mean ternary operators? In Perl: `my $value = $cond ? $value_if_true : $value_if_false;` or `return $cond ? $value_if_true : $value_if_false;`